# wordpress custom post show some post in a div and rest posts in some different div

Tags: loops, custom-post-type, wordpress

In wordpress I have made a custom post type. So for custom post type my code looks like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'broker_post_type' );
function broker_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'new_broker',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Brands' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Brand' )
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
    )
  );
}
```

To show the contents of custom posts through shortcode I have done like this

```
function display_broker_posts() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'new_broker',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  );

  $dee_bios = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $dee_bios->have_posts() ):
    $dee_output = '<div id="brokers-wrap">';
    $dee_output .= '<div id="brokers-bg-wrap">';
    $dee_output .= '<div class="brokers-content">';
    $dee_output .= '<div class="brokers-left-content">';
    while ( $dee_bios->have_posts() ) : $dee_bios->the_post();
      if( $dee_bios->current_post == 0 || ( $dee_bios->current_post % 2 ) == 0 ) {
        $dee_output .= '<a class="branding first" href=""><div class="one-half first">';
        }
      else {
        $dee_output .= '<a href="" class="branding"><div class="one-half">';
        }

      $dee_output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $dee_bios->post->ID,'small', 'bios', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
      $dee_output .= '<span></span>';
    //  $dee_output .= '<p><strong>' . get_the_title() . ',</strong> ' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
      $dee_output .= '</div><!--end .one-half-->';
    endwhile;
    $dee_output .= '<div class="clear"></div><!--clear all floats-->';
    $dee_output .= '</div><!-- end #bios-->';
  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $dee_output;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_brokers', 'display_broker_posts' );
```

Here its working fine. I can see the featured image in my page by using shortcode. But lets say I have `20 custom posts and I want that the first 6 will show in a different div and another 14 in another div`. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$dee_bios = new WP_Query( $args );
$i = 0;
if( $dee_bios->have_posts() ):
  while ( $dee_bios->have_posts() ) : $dee_bios->the_post();
    if ($i ==0) {
       $dee_output .= '<div id="first_broker_div">';
    } elseif ($i == 6) {
       $dee_output .= '</div><div id="second_broker_div">';
    }
    $dee_output .= //Your post content
    $i++;
  endwhile;
  $dee_output .= '</div>';
endif;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but whatever the condition it may be in your code it is showing <div id="first_broker_div"> So can you tell me how to solve this?